# pass a string array to web service in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have developed an iPhone application where I need to pass a string array to the web service.
Now, I have a `NSMutable` array, say `sendSelectedID`.

I know I have values in the array, because when I display in for loop

```
for(i=0;i<[sendSelectedID count];i++)
{
NSLog(@"%@", [sendSelectedID objectAtindex:i]);
}
```

this is the way I pass the `NSMutable` array to the Soap message:

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
   @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
   "<S:Envelope xmlns:S=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
   "<S:Header/\>\n"
   "<S:Body>\n"
   "<ns2:confirmRecallDeposit xmlns:ns2=\"http://services.cbp.syntel.org/\">\n"
   "<TransactionId>%@</TransactionId>\n"
   "</ns2:confirmRecallDeposit>\n"
   "</S:Body>\n"
   "</S:Envelope>\n",sendSelectedID ];
```

and the soap message is displayed like:

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
  @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
 "<S:Envelope xmlns:S=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
  "<S:Header/\>\n"
  "<S:Body>\n"
  "<ns2:confirmRecallDeposit xmlns:ns2=\"http://services.cbp.syntel.org/\">\n"
  "<TransactionId>(
        1,
        3
      )</TransactionId>\n"
  "</ns2:confirmRecallDeposit>\n"
  "</S:Body>\n"
  "</S:Envelope>\n",sendSelectedID ];
```

But on the server side, it gives error Number format exception.
How am I to remove this error on the server side? I tried to trim the values recieved, but it did not work.

Comment: your question is extremely difficult to understand.  what is wrong with the output you're seeing?  what is the desired output?  what are 'receib' and 'ved'?  what does the actual code look like?

Comment: You've asked 17 questions and you haven't marked any with a correct answer flag?

Comment: iPlease tell me how am i to flag as correct answer, i tried  one. i clicked flag button, It gave me  a message, requires moderator, then in the text box i typed Correct answer. is it the same way i need to do

Comment: You don't use the flag option to mark an accepted answer - you click the green checkmark outline to do so. You're unlikely to receive answers for your questions unless you mark accepted answers appropriately because people usually won't spend their time with an answer if they won't gain reputation for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but perhaps you need to escape the carriage returns in `sendSelectedID`.

You could add the method `-stringByEscapingMetacharacters` to an `NSString` category (a way to extend functionality to `NSString`):

```
@implementation NSString (Additions)

- (NSUInteger) numberOfUnsafeCharacters {
    NSUInteger i, len, cnt;

    if ((len = [self length]) == 0)
        return 0;

    for (i = 0, cnt = 0; i < len; i++) {
        unichar c;

        c = [self characterAtIndex:i];
        if (c == ',' || c == ';' || c == '\n' || c == '\\') cnt++;
    }
    return cnt;
}

- (NSString *) stringByEscapingMetacharacters {
    NSUInteger i, cnt, len;
    unichar  *newStr;
    NSString *result;

    if ((cnt = [self numberOfUnsafeCharacters]) == 0)
        return self;

    len = [self length];
    newStr = calloc(len + cnt + 10, sizeof(unichar));
    for (i = 0, cnt = 0; i < len; i++) {
        unichar c;

        c = [self characterAtIndex:i];
        if (c == '\\') {
            newStr[i + cnt] = '\\';
            cnt++;
        }
        else if (c == '\n') {
            newStr[i + cnt] = '\\';
            cnt++;
            c = 'n';
        }
        newStr[i + cnt] = c;
    }
    newStr[i + cnt] = '\0';
    result = [NSString stringWithCharacters:newStr length:(i + cnt)];
    if (newStr != NULL) free(newStr); newStr = NULL;

    return result;
}
```

Then you would call `[sendSelectedID stringByEscapingMetacharacters]` to get the following `NSString*`:

```
(\\n1,\\n3\\n)
```

Instead of what you have now:

```
(
1,
3
)
```